# SSL no cipher NULL-SHA

Tags: c, ssl, tls1.2

I want to use SSL without data encryption in C. I have used the NULL-SHA in order to do this. My client application connects to the server and sends the "ABCDE" string and the server prints received string.

Client and server applications work good, but the problem is:

When I capture TCP packets with wireshark, I could not find the string "ABCDE" in TCP packets' data. I suppose that without any encryption, I could find that.

One more thing, when I don't set the NULL-SHA (using SSL with data encryption), the TCP packet's data has 53 bytes (for sending the "ABCDE"). If I set that, it has 31 bytes. It shows that the NULL-SHA removes the encryption, because transmitted data length has been reduced for the same transmitted string "ABCDE".

Any help?

Comment: Send 10-20 equal values to see what is transiting.

Comment: Unfortunately, when client sends "AAAAAAAAAA" in a loop to server, tcp packets have 29 byte data, without any 'A'.

Comment: What is your SSL provider? Is it _OpenSSL_? If so, does it support _NULL-*_ ciphers? can check that by running `${PATH_TO/}openssl ciphers`.

Comment: There is no`NULL-*` ciphers. Why when I use the `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx,"NULL-SHA")` I give no error?

Comment: @CristiFati `openssl ciphers` by default will not list `NULL` ciphers. Per https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html *The default cipher list. This is determined at compile time and is normally ALL:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT:!eNULL.*  If you want to see *all* the ciphers your `openssl` version supports, `openssl ciphers 'ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL:eNULL:aNULL'` works (and likely is somewhat redundant, but given the complexity of OpenSSL I personally prefer such reduncancies).

Comment: What does `openssl s_client -cipher eNULL -connect server:port` show?

Comment: @Andrew Henle: Thank you for the pointers, I just ran the augmented `openssl` command, and it also returned the _NULL_ ciphers.